# How to style a part of a text without using html tags?

Tags: css

and I want to make "TV:", "OVA:" and so on... bold or give them another color.
but I can't edit the HTML I can only edit the CSS. is there any way of doing/going about this?
example I'm using the following:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <td class="category_totals"> 
                TV: 9, 
                OVA: 2, 
                Movies: 0,
                <span title="Specials">Spcl.</span>: 0,
                Eps: 113,
                <span title="Downloaded Episodes">DL Eps</span>: 0,
                Days: 1.90, 
                Mean Score: 7.0, 
                Score <span title="Deviation">Dev.</span>: 0.29
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

I can also not use JS as far as I know.

Comment: You require more markup to accomplish this.  You should spend some effort on determining if you can use javascript; you will need it to alter the DOM if you can't edit the html source directly.

Comment: sadly I can't use javascript they filter out the tags. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. In CSS, you can style only elements and pseudo-elements. There is no pseudo-element that could be used for purposes like this.